# снимок с камеры на python, получаю ошибку

Tags: python, камера, web-camera

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

for i in range(30):
    cap.read()
   
ret, frame = cap.read()

cv2.imwrite('cam.png', frame)   

cap.release()
```

У меня вышла вот такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ipcam.py", line 14, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite('cam.png', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-cf
f9bdsm\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:738: error: (-215:Assertion fai
led) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
```

Comment: `ret` скорее всего `False`

Comment: ipcam.py -- так называется Ваш файл?

Comment: hedgehogues - да